# Increment column value using Slick for postgres

Tags: postgresql, slick

I need to add 1 to column value for a record in postgres table based on some filter. Suppose I have two fields `id` and `count` and I want to increment count value by 1.

So far I have

```
MyTable.filter(_.id === someId).map(_.count).update(??)
```

Not sure how if it is possible to use `update` to do so. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently, this is not supported in Slick - https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/497. You could:

1. Use a plain SQL query; or
2. Retrieve the current "count" value in a separate query, increment, then do the update, using the [transactionally](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/api/index.html#slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$JdbcActionExtensionMethods@transactionally:DBIOAction[R,S,EwithTransactional]) modifier to force the use of one transaction. Though, depending on the level of transaction isolation in your database, the use of a transaction might not be enough to avoid race conditions.